# How to use namespaces and classes?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am learning C++ (I usually code in C) and I don't understand how to use namespaces and classes. Do they have to be declared in header files? How do I declare functions in a namespace? And let's say I am working on a large project with different files. And I define a namespace in a file, but then want to add more functions to that same namespace, but those functions are defined in another file. Can that be done? For example:

**file1.cpp**

```
namespace Example {
   int vartest;
   void foo();
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
int othervar;
void otherfoo(); // How can I add this and othervar to the Example namespace?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are coming in from C, you may find anonymous namespaces to be a useful replacement for `static`. `namespace { bool Ireturntrue(){ return true; } }` is now nicely walled away and won't add to name pollution when linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declare it an equivalent<sup>1</sup> `namespace` of the same *"name"* !

**file1.cpp**

```
namespace Example {
   int vartest;
   void foo();
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
namespace Example {
    int othervar;
    void otherfoo();
}
```

Namespaces are merged.

> Do they have to be declared in header files?

No. You can declare any `namespace` inside a `namespace`. (Note that the "global scope" is also a `namespace`)

> How do I declare functions in a namespace?

Simply declare it within the `namespace`. As you have done.

> And let's say I am working on a large project with different files.
>   And I define a namespace in a file, but then want to add more
>   functions to that same namespace, but those functions are defined in
>   another file. Can that be done?

Namespaces of the same name, within the same namespace are merged.

```
namespace X { void foo(){} }
namespace X { void foo(){} }  //Error, redefinition of `foo` because the namespace ::X is merged
```

---

```
namespace X { void foo(){} }
namespace Y { void foo(){} }  //Ok. Different name spaces...
```

---

```
namespace X { void foo(){} }  // ::X
namespace Y { void foo(){} }  // ::Y

namespace Y {
   namespace X {  // namespace ::Y::X here isn't same as ::X
     void foo(){}  //OK
   }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *recall that the so called "global scope" is actually a namespace known as `global namespace`*

Comment: plus 1 for last note on global namespace.